# How to turn an array of date components into a JavaScript date object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, date, datetime

So I have an API endpoint returning dates to me as an array, like this:

```
{
  date: [
    '2016',
    '4',
    '2',
    '10',
    '3',
    '23'
  ]
}
```

What's the easiest / tersest way to turn this into a date object, so that I can sort objects? The lack of leading zeros and presence of minutes & hours makes me think it is quite difficult?

Comment: `new Date(...)`, parameters depend on your parameter sort.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`new Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) with correction for month (zero based).

> ```
> new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);
> ```

```
var date = new Date(object.date[0], object.date[1] - 1, object.date[2], object.date[3], object.date[4], object.date[5]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're asking for the easiest way. Then here you are.

```js
var obj = {
  date: [
    '2016',
    '4',
    '2',
    '10',
    '3',
    '23'
  ]
};
--obj.date[1];
console.log(new Date(...obj.date));
```

From the MDN article of [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), the `month` argument is an *Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December*. This means you need to reduce the actual month's value by 1.

This solution also uses [spread operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

Comment: If you want something equally terse but works in **all** browsers, replace the last line with `new Date(Date.UTC.apply(null, obj.date))` but that treats the values as UTC.

Answer (score 1):

If your array is fixed you can use the following

```js
var dt={
  date: [
    '2016',
    '4',
    '2',
    '10',
    '3',
    '23'
  ]
};

//assuming first component is YYYY, second is MM, third is DD then HH:MM:SS
alert(new Date(dt.date[0]+"-"+((dt.date[1] - 1) < 10 ? "0" + (dt.date[1]-1) : (dt.date[1]-1))+"-"+ (dt.date[2] < 10 ? "0" + dt.date[2] : dt.date[2])  + "T" + (dt.date[3] < 10 ? "0" + dt.date[3] : dt.date[3]) + ":" + (dt.date[4] < 10 ? "0"+dt.date[4] :dt.date[4]) +":" + (dt.date[5] < 10 ? "0"+dt.date[5] :dt.date[5])))
```

Comment: Thanks for that :)

Comment: Why build a string that must then be parsed? Just pass the parts directly to the Date constructor as values, not a string.

Comment: @A1rPun I have since modified my answer.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the running snippet? @NinaScholz

Comment: you miss leading zeroes and a T instead of a space. `new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00');`

Comment: Fixed. Although I like @Tresdin's answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Extended solution for sorting an array of "dates"(after converting) using `Date.getTime` and `Array.sort` functions:

```js
var dates = [
    { date: [ '2016','4','2','10','3','23'] },
    { date: [ '2016','4','1','10','3','23'] },
    { date: [ '2016','4','3','11','3','23'] }

];

dates.sort(function(a,b){
    // compound date string in form: "2016,4,2 10:3:23" to pass into Date constructor
    var aDate_str = a.date.slice(0,3).join() + " " + a.date.slice(3).join(":"),
        bDate_str = b.date.slice(0,3).join() + " " + b.date.slice(3).join(":"),
        aTime = (new Date(aDate_str)).getTime(), // getting date as the number of milliseconds
        bTime = (new Date(bDate_str)).getTime();

    return (aTime == bTime)? 0 : ((aTime < bTime)? -1 : 1);
});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(dates, 0, 4) + "</pre>");
```

Comment: @NinaScholz, pay attention to this author's phrase "to turn this into a date object, so that I can sort objects?". Don't you think ?